# Accessing HYCOM Hindcasts using Siphon: OPENDAP is not available for this dataset

Tags: python-siphon

I've got a working example of using Siphon to access the HYCOM forecast model run catalog (FMRC), and I really like this pattern! My problem is that I cannot access the hindcast catalog in the same way.

Here is what works, note the [THREDDS catalog URL](https://tds.hycom.org/thredds/catalogs/GLBy0.08/expt_93.0.html) and how the HTML appears in a browser:

```
from siphon.catalog import TDSCatalog
thredds_url_fmrc = "https://tds.hycom.org/thredds/catalog/GLBy0.08/expt_93.0/FMRC/runs/catalog.xml"
cat_fmrc = TDSCatalog(thredds_url_fmrc)
ds_fmrc = cat_fmrc.datasets[0].remote_access()
```

Here is what does not work:

```
from siphon.catalog import TDSCatalog
thredds_url_hind = "https://tds.hycom.org/thredds/catalogs/GLBy0.08/expt_93.0.xml"
cat_hind = TDSCatalog(thredds_url_hind)
ds_hind = cat_hind.datasets[0].remote_access()
```

This returns `ValueError: OPENDAP is not available for this dataset`.

Note that both the FMRC and hindcasts are nested within this [higher level catalog](https://tds.hycom.org/thredds/catalogs/GLBy0.08/expt_93.0.html). The browser-rendered catalog pages for the FMRC look quite different that what is available for the hindcast data, but [the hindcast data does indicate the catalog entry](https://tds.hycom.org/thredds/catalogs/GLBy0.08/expt_93.0.html?dataset=GLBy0.08-expt_93.0) as I've used in the above example.

I feel like I'm just pointing Siphon at the wrong URL, or that the HYCOM THREDDS server has [perhaps been disabled for higher level requests that are too big?](https://groups.google.com/a/hycom.org/g/forum/c/FCrquiTPidc/m/VG2qX2-taioJ)

I've cross-posted this issue with less Siphon specificity on [the HYCOM user's group.](https://groups.google.com/a/hycom.org/g/forum/c/ISuBwaGWbDw/m/lfOozJtQAAAJ)

Any help/input is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug somewhere in Siphon. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out a work-around, so right now you'll have to copy the correct OPeNDAP URL and pass that to `Dataset` from netCDF4-python or `xarray.open_dataset` manually. I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/Unidata/siphon/issues/734) to look at later.

Comment: Ryan, thanks very much for the prompt response. Been following your work for a while now. 

As you suggested, I'll add here that the following is the work around for me at present: 
tmpds = xr.open_dataset("https://tds.hycom.org/thredds/dodsC/GLBy0.08/expt_93.0/uv3z", decode_times=False)